# How to change the legend in a choropleth map to go from highest to lowest?

Tags: r, tmap

- My code:

```r
    qtm(merged_CLIH,fill = "X.6",
    borders = "gray",
    fill.style="quantile",
    fill.breaks=c(0,10,20,30,40,100),
    fill.palette="Purples",
    fill.title="% children living in benefit claimant households")+
  tm_compass(position = c("RIGHT","TOP"))+
  tm_layout(legend.outside = TRUE,main.title = "Choropleth map of % Children living in benefit claimant households")
```

- Please find my current map just below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mumena, welcome to SO! Please make accessible your data (or an excerpt of it) so that we can best help you. There is also something that is not clear to me: do you want to reverse the order of the values or the order of the colors in the legend or both? Cheers.

Comment: @Mumena Your % children living in benefit claimant households value is probably a character value that is being alphabetized in the legend (note first number in value increases, from 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, to 9). I'm guess you also don't want white to represent ~10.2% and dark purple 9.6% though they are close in value. As before, if you provide a complete example with some of your dataset (e.g., use `dput(head(df))` if `df` is your data.frame) you will likely get more assistance.